# how to use network.onDisconnect in ionic4

Tags: networking, angular7, ionic4

I'm using ionic 4 in code use network

not working network.onDisconnect() in my project

I'm add import

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

and

```
npm install @ionic-native/network@5.9.0
```

not working code :

```
this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
  alert("FirstPage onDisconnect");
},
(error) => {
  alert(error);
});
this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('network was connected :-)');
  alert("FirstPage onConnect");
},
(error) => {
  alert(error);
});
```

or code:

```
this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
  alert("FirstPage onDisconnect");
});
this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('network was connected :-)');
  alert("FirstPage onConnect");
});
```

or code:

```
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
    alert("FirstPage onDisconnect");
   });
   this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('network was connected :-)');
    alert("FirstPage onConnect");
   });
  });
```

or code :

```
 window.addEventListener('online', function() {
   alert("ONLINE");
 }, false);

 window.addEventListener('offline', function() {
   alert("OFFLINE");
 }, false);
```

or code:

```
document.addEventListener('online', function() {
  alert("ONLINE");
}, false);

document.addEventListener('offline', function() {
  alert("OFFLINE");
}, false);
```

ionic info:

```
 Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.5.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

 Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, browser 5.0.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova- 
   plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.0, (and 10 other plugins)

 System:

   NodeJS : v10.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

even add import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx'; in app.module.ts
add providers network

how to use this.network.onDisconnect() and this.network.onConnect() in my project ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is the correct code:

```
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
    alert("FirstPage onDisconnect");
   });
   this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('network was connected :-)');
    alert("FirstPage onConnect");
   });
  });
```

It should be run in the constructor, where are you calling this?

Also why are you specifically targeting v5.9.0 of the plugin?

I would just use:

```
npm install @ionic-native/network
```

Comment: hi
I using my code in constructor 
and
using version 5.9.0
and use npm install @ionic-native/network

but not working

import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx'; is ture?

Comment: ah ok i just checked, 5.9.0 is the latest version. I thought maybe you had followed some outdated tutorial. Are you testing this on an actual device? Not through emulator, devapp, or browser?

Comment: yes, I using latest version @ionic-native/network and testing in actual device but not working!